# Is there any automated tool to generate a script for me to view and edit data based on database table

Tags: python, web-applications, postgresql

Currently, I am having Apache running, a PostgreSQL database, and several Python CGI script. I just don't want to write additional script to manipulate the following simple table structure.

```
Machine Name | IP Address
=========================
```

I was wondering, is there any tool, which can help me to **auto generate** a script/web page for me based on that table, so that I can **view and edit** the content through web browser? What keyword I should google for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would mysitemaker do what you need? How about phppgadmin?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysitemaker/

http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/